# how browser find collection elements when we are using css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

I want to know how browsers find html collection elements when we use css selector.for example.

```
<div>
    <p class="color">I'm p1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <p class="color">I'm p2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="color">I'm p3</p>
```

when we use $("p") or $(".color") we will get three p elements.
so,my question is the order of finding those elements.
(p1,p2,p3) or  (p3,p1,p2) or others
because html is a dom tree,the browser may use tree traversal algorithms,which have 5 kinds of(depth-first,pre,in,post,breadth).So,which algorithm is the browser taken.

Comment: It uses **depth-first pre-order traversal** as mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Here is another link with various references related to browser internals :http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Answer (score 0):

In that specific use case you will get:

```
I'm p1
I'm p2
I'm p3
```

even without to use jQuery.

```
var p = $(".color");
for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
    var el = p.eq(i);
    console.log(el.text());
}
console.log("test");
var p2 = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
for(var i=0; i<p2.length; i++) {
    var el = p2[i];
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
}
```

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/RSEyf/3/

So, it looks like the browser gets the elements in their order in the html.

It is the same even if you use just *p* instead of *.color*.